# How do I get the JQuery to work with the iCheck Plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, icheck

I've been trying to apply iCheck plugins to my radio and check boxes and I just cannot figure out why my radio buttons keep selecting more than a single option, with no experience in JQuery, I think I might need help with this. I used minimal blue skin so I downloaded the blue.css with the blue.png sprite image, jquery-1.11.3.min.js and icheck.js.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="check.js"></script>


<link rel="stylesheet" href="blue.css">

<script>
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $('input').iCheck({
        checkboxClass: 'icheckbox_minimal-blue',
        radioClass: 'iradio_minimal-blue',
        increaseArea: '20%'//optional                                
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<label>
<div class="icheckbox_minimal-blue disabled">
    <input type="checkbox" name="quux[1]" disabled>
    </div>
    Foo
    </label>

<label for="baz[1]">Bar</label>
<div class="iradio_minimal-blue checked">
  <input type="radio" name="quux[2]" id="baz[1]" checked>
</div>

<label for="baz[2]">Bar</label>
   <div class="iradio_minimal-blue">
   <input type="radio" name="quux[2]" id="baz[2]">
</div></br>

<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is there any error in console(F12)

Comment: @KarthikeyanVaithilingam I'm not sure what you mean by console but I'm using Chrome to test it.

Comment: I meant the  Developer Tools Console. You can open Dev Tools by pressing F12

Comment: @KarthikeyanVaithilingam Oh, I didn't try F12 but I will right now and come back to you.

Comment: @KarthikeyanVaithilingam I solved it using F12, some unwanted code I added in my iCheck.js file by mistake. Thank You.

Comment: @KarthikeyanVaithilingam Now the problem I have is, the radio buttons are picking more than a single option. Even with the identical names in the inputs.

Comment: Please update your question. I never used iCheck you will get the answers from other.

Answer (score 0):

You have to give same name to all your radio inputs.

```
<div class="iradio_minimal-blue checked">
  <input type="radio" name="quux" id="baz[1]" checked>
</div>

<label for="baz[2]">Bar</label>
   <div class="iradio_minimal-blue">
   <input type="radio" name="quux" id="baz[2]">
</div></br>
```